# javascript : compare content of two array of objects by some id and return true or false

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i need a little help to compare two array of objects and look if the array A has the same content of array B by using an id who is inside both arrays, for example:

```html
example false:

ArrayObjectA = [{
      id: 1,
      name: josh,
      age: 31
      },{
      id: 2,
      name: Kyle,
      age: 21}];
    
ArrayObjectB = [{
      id: 1,
      name: josh,
      age: 31
      }];
      
      
ArrayObjectB content is equals to ArrayObjectA => false

example true:

ArrayObjectA = [{
      id: 1,
      name: josh,
      age: 31
      },{
      id: 2,
      name: Kyle,
      age: 21}];
    
ArrayObjectB = [{
      id: 1,
      name: josh,
      age: 31
      },{
      id: 2,
      name: Kyle,
      age: 21}];
      
ArrayObjectB content is equals to ArrayObjectA => true
```

i found a library called lodash but i dont know if is useful.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get ids list from each array and check if all elements are equal

```js
const compareArrays = (arr1, arr2) => {
  const ids1 = arr1.map(v => v.id).sort() 
  const ids2 = arr2.map(v => v.id).sort()

  return ids1.length === ids2.length && ids1.every((v, ind) => v === ids2[ind])
}
```